# Appcelerator Windows Phone (run, build, liveview)

Tags: windows, windows-phone, appcelerator, local, liveview

I've an Alloy app compatible with iOS and android, now I need to make it compatible with Windows Phone, but I've some questions about Windows Phone SDK and Appcelerator for building Windows Phones apps.

The problem is: I've only 2 options to run the app on windows (device or windows phone emulator), there is no local windows option.

So, every time that I wan't to compile and run it, I've to run it on appc terminal:

```
cd "C:\Users\Ricardo\Documents\Appcelerator\projectTest"
appc run -p windows -T ws-local
```

There is any short cut for this operation? or this option in the top left run/build/package options?

Also, it would be great to use LiveView with windows phone app development, but isn't compatible yet, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,Local Windows build (ws_local) option is missing in the Appcelerator Studio but you can always run directly from the terminal.

Here is the supporting ticket to address this problem - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8502.

Windows liveview is not yet supported - which is scheduled for next version of Studio

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm building through CLI, and I've also tried to add --liveview but it throws the LiveView error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable

Comment: That's addressed with https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23678. It will be part of next SDK release. You can give a try with SDK 6.1.0 nightly build.